# Sequelize query string prefix / starts with

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm building an autofill function that takes a string input and returns a list of string suggestions.

Sequelize's `iLike:query` returns every string in which the queried string appears. I would like to favour strings for which the query is a prefix. For example when `query='sh'` then the results should return strings that start with `sh` instead of having `sh` anywhere within the string.

This is relatively simple to do after receiving the data from the DB, however I was wondering if there is a way to accomplish this via sequelize while querying the DB? If so how?

The DB size will be between 10,000 and 100,000 strings of no more than a handful of words (company names to be exact).

Optional question: DB's usually have superior performance to generically written code, in this circumstance should there even be a noticeable difference? Or should I just collect all the data from the DB and apply some other filters on it after via vanilla JS.

```
let suggestions = yield db.Company.findAll({
  limit: 7,
    where: {
      company_name: {
        $iLike: '%'+this.data.query
      }
    }
 })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like this is super easy! The `'%'` acts like a `*` from regex. So `query + '%'` returns any results where query is the prefix.

```
let suggestions = yield db.Company.findAll({
    limit: 5,
    where: { $or: [
      { stock_ticker: { $ilike: query + '%' } },
      { company_name: { $ilike: query + '%' } }
    ]},
    order: '"volume" DESC'
  })
```